# Attempting to access Shared files on Windows Server from Java program running in UNIX

Tags: java, unix

I'm currently trying to create a Java program which will automate reports.  I have only one issue that's stopping me (so far) and 
was wondering if anyone tried this before and know a work around.

My Java program is successfully running locally using NetBeans on my Windows XP Professional PC using the following file paths: 
File filex = new File("\\10.78.0.99\\ITX1DATA\\CLOSET\\DClean\\MPHMETRICS\\MPH Daily Volume Report.xlsx");

FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("\\10.78.0.99\\ITX1DATA\\PROVIDER\\DClean\\MPHMETRICS\\'PS.PRIME.NPI.DAILY.METRICS'");

FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("\\10.78.0.99\\ITX1DATA\\PROVIDER\\DClean\\MPHMETRICS\\MPH Daily Volume Report.xlsx");

However, when I logon to the UNIX Dev server:  (Echisxtlmapp12 - 10.131.13.36)  and I: 
1) Switch file paths to use Java version 1.6  which works. 
PATH=/usr/bin:/etc:/usr/sbin:/usr/ucb:/usr/bin/X11:/sbin:/usr/java6/jre/bin:/usr/java6/bin:/usr/java131/jre/bin:/usr/java131/bin:$PATH ; export PATH

2) Do a change directory to my program directory 
cd MphMetrics

3) Run the program 
java -jar MPHDAILY.jar

I get the error message: 
Error: \10.78.0.99\ITX1DATA\PROVIDER\DClean\MPHMETRICS\MPH Daily Volume Report.xlsx (A file or directory in the path name does not exist.)

I'm able to successfully ping the server ping 10.78.0.99 which contains the shared files from the UNIX server.

It would make sense if I ran it locally and it did not work, but it works locally w/o issue.

Thought I run it by you to see if anyone tried running a Java program this way using network drives. 
Ultimately I will be creating a Unix Shell script of Daemon service which will run 7 days a week creating MPH report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to use a library which is able to "talk Windows".

And there is one: [JCIFS](http://jcifs.samba.org), by the good folks at Samba. Link to javadoc [here](http://jcifs.samba.org/src/docs/api/).

Comment: Is the problem that a Java program running under UNIX cannot directly access shared folders on a Windows Server?

Comment: Not with UNCs as you use them, they can't. This is a Windows specific notation. On the other hand, the underlying protocol, SMB, is cross platform -- after all, Samba has been able to access Windows networks for a long time, and even act as PDC.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try using Samba to get my UNIX java program to access the Windows Server shared folders.